# Angular child route observer

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

In Angular5 app I have routing defined like this:

```
path: 'my-object/:id',
    component: MyObjectDetailComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'sublist', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'sublist', component: PointComponent},
        {path: 'new', component: PointFormComponent},
    ],
```

in MyObjectDetailComponent template file I have:

```
<button #new />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I need to hide some interface objects (like new button) when I show PointForm to the user.

I believe I need to add some kind of observer to url or route - but have no idea how to do that (and where).

It should hide `<button #new />` (and some other UI elements) when user enters PointFormComponent (path: new) and show them again when he leaves it.

Comment: so you want to hide when url `http://domain//new` ??

Comment: Yes, it is exactly: "domain/object/:id/new"

Comment: try out my answer might work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this , means you need to check for route change, if changed route contains new in it then put hideflag true and hide contorls

```
class MyClass {
  hideInputs = false;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      const href = window.location.href;
       this.hideInputs = href.endsWith('/new');
    });
  }
}


<button *ngIf="hideInputs " #new />
```

Comment: Works perfectly, so simple :)

I just changed `includes('new')` for `href.endsWith('/new')` and 'hideInputs' for `isEditing`

Comment: @Robert - ok , thats good basically concept is to subscribe for route events and perform activity

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this in your MyObjectDetailComponent:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class MyObjectDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    currentUrl: string;

    constructor(private router:Router) {  }

    ngOnInit() {
        // that´s how you get the current url
        currentUrl = this.router.url; 
    }
}
```

And add something like this in your template

```
<button *ngIf="currentUrl == ![add path to "new" url here]" #new />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: This would not work, because OnInit is not fired when I switch child routes.